# Как реализовать такую рамку на html/сcs?

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Желательно максимально универсальное решение без костылей)

Comment: `<fieldset><legend><span>Hire us<span></legend></fieldset>` например так

Comment: как сделать, чтобы снизу был разрыв? про классический филдсет, о котором вы говорите, знаю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант убрать `border-bottom` у блока и добавить 2 линии с помощью псевдоэлементов:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.wrapper p {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.wrapper a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid white;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.wrapper::before,
.wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper::before {
  left: 0;
}

.wrapper::after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia nostrum ad optio, eius nemo, accusamus odit dolor culpa distinctio, beatae eos? Itaque nam magni harum? Pariatur recusandae molestias placeat ut?</p>
  <a href="#">Button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: я уже хотел до утра подождать - думал если ни кто не сможет я сделаю

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, да вроде бы всё просто, правда я всё усложняю на `CSS`, может есть вариант покороче

Comment: всё сделано безупречно ....

Comment: @St1myL Круто, спасибо!